# Gitlab + Cockpit: Prometheus 100% CPU usage

Tags: gitlab, port, prometheus, cpu-usage, cockpit

I'm using Cockpit to monitor a server with Gitlab.

Since I installed Cockpit, Gitlab is using 100% of my CPU.
When I check with `htop`, I see this is a Gitlab component, prometheus.

**Solution:**

While I'm writing this question, I found a solution.

Prometheus and Cockpit use the same port by default (9090).
I just have to change the Cockpit port to another and everything goes to normal :)

On Ubuntu Server 18.04, edit `/etc/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/cockpit.socket` like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Cockpit Web Service Socket
Documentation=man:cockpit-ws(8)

[Socket]
ListenStream=XXXX <-- Change port here.
ExecStartPost=-/bin/ln -sf /usr/share/cockpit/issue/active.issue /run/cockpit/issue
ExecStopPost=-/bin/ln -sf /usr/share/cockpit/issue/inactive.issue /run/cockpit/issue

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

Then reload `systemd` config and restart Cockpit:

```sh
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart cockpit.socket
```

That's all!